# Plotting the spectrum of a continuous sinusoid function

Tags: frequency-spectrum, continuous-signals

I am just learning about spectrums and I am a little confused. I have given a simple example and where I get stuck.

> Plot the spectrum of  $x(t) = 5\cos\left(800\pi t + \frac{3 \pi}{7}\right)$.

So I use reverse-Euler's to write this as 
$$x(t) = \frac{5 e^{i \frac{3 \pi}{7}}}{2} e^{i 800\pi t} + \frac{5 e^{-i \frac{3 \pi}{7}}}{2} e^{-i 800\pi t}$$

- What is the spectral amplitude in each case? I am unclear if the frequency of $800 \pi t$ has amplitude $5$ or $\frac{5 e^{-i \frac{3 \pi}{7}}}{2}$.
- If it is the second do I make two seperate plots for the complex and real parts, or do I just plot $\bigg\lvert \frac{5 e^{-i \frac{3 \pi}{7}}}{2}\bigg\rvert $?

Answer (score 2):

Given your signal $x(t) = 5\cos(800\pi t + \frac{3 \pi}{7})$. And considering your correct decomposition of it into complex exponentials:

$$x(t) = \frac{5 e^{i \frac{3 \pi}{7}}}{2} e^{i 800\pi t} + \frac{5 e^{-i \frac{3 \pi}{7}}}{2} e^{-i 800\pi t}$$

You next apply the continuous-Fourier transform properties to get:

$$X(\Omega) =  5\pi \left( e^{i \frac{3 \pi}{7}} \delta(\Omega - 800\pi) + e^{-i \frac{3 \pi}{7}} \delta(\Omega + 800\pi) \right)$$

Now your Fourier transform has two **impulses** with **weights** of $5\pi e^{i \frac{3 \pi}{7}}$ and $5\pi e^{-i \frac{3 \pi}{7}}$ respectively.

The spectral **amplitudes** are **infinite**, by definition of the impulse function, but they have the weight respectively. And for the **magnitude** you would take the absolute value of the amplitudes, which is therefore infinite. Yet again you can represent the magnitudes of those impulses by their weights' absolute value.